# How to extract and read entries of zip file which is sent as a byte array

Tags: java, junit

In a nutshell I'm trying to write a method which receives the Zip file as byte[] array, and what I want to do is to return the number of entries (the files) that are in the Zip file and test if they're 6 entries.

Here is what I've done so far, which throws `FileNotFoundException` on `line 3`

```
  public List<ZipEntry> extractZipEntries(byte[] content) throws IOException {
    List<ZipEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(content.toString()); //Line 3

    for (Enumeration<?> e = zip.entries(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
        ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
        entries.add(entry);
    }
    return entries;
  }
```

test is here:

```
 List<ZipEntry> zipEntries = SomeClassName.extractZipEntries(content);
 assertTrue(zipEntries.size() == 6);
```

Also if possible suggest a better approach, but ideally what I doing above is straight forward here.

Thanks!

Comment: ZipFile only takes a file or filename as a constructor not a content stream.

Comment: So what do I need to do?

Comment: You could first write the stream to a file and then open it.

Comment: @Simple-Solution follow the answer given below and use a ZipInputStream

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seeing as the source is a `byte[]`, you'll need to use a `ByteArrayInputStream` to read the file.

```
public List<ZipEntry> extractZipEntries(byte[] content) throws IOException {
    List<ZipEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

    ZipInputStream zi = null;
    try {
        zi = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(content));

        ZipEntry zipEntry = null;
        while ((zipEntry = zi.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            entries.add(zipEntry);
        }
    } finally {
        if (zi != null) {
            zi.close();
        }
    }
    return entries;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did too